# MongoDB unresponsive after creating an index on a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with 10 million records. I executed command to create index:

```
db.web_tech.createIndex({"applications.name":1}).
```

After one minute of execution it gives me error:

> 2017-02-11T06:57:24.839+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:0, in(connect), reason:
>   Connection refused.

When I am trying to login to mongodb it is not allowing me to login.

I am running MongoDB on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of my problem, the error was because of RAM. I was having only 1GB RAM which was insufficient to perform indexing on such a big database.

Thanks for all your answers hope it will help other people.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an index on such a large collection is going to be a very expensive operation and your system probably doesn't have enough resource to handle anything else whilst it's being created. You can either wait for the operation to complete or restart the MongoDB process.

To avoid blocking all other database activities the [`background`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) flag should be set when creating an index on collection.

```
db.web_tech.createIndex({"applications.name":1}, {"background": true})
```